# How to display videos in mobile using WML?

Tags: debugging, video, mobile-website, file-format, wap

Doing WAP project using WML, in that I have to display videos to play in WML. I used
`<embed>`, `<object>` tags but it's not working in mobile. Anybody can help me and solve this issue?

Comment: .3gp and .rm format videos to display in mobile using wml

Comment: What have you tried? Please post the code you have, and pin point where you are having a problem.

Comment: I used this tag <embed src="video path name" Pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/" width="<%=vdWdth%>" height="<%=vdHgt%>" CONTROLLER="true" LOOP="false" AUTOPLAY="false" name="Video"></embed> and <object></object> tag also used but its not acceptable in mobile.

Comment: Please edit your question with the extra information, so that people won't have to read through all the comments to be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use animated gifs or SMIL to show video in WML:

- [Generate gif animation from a video](http://wiki.alessandro.delgallo.net/wiki/index.php/Encoding_from_command_line#Generate_gif89a_.28-gif_animation.29_mplayer_from_a_video)
- [convert avi to 3gp using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598108/convert-avi-to-3gp-using-ffmpeg)
- [SMIL 2.1 Mobile Profile](http://www.w3.org/TR/2005/WD-SMIL2-20050201/smil21-mobile-profile.html)