# convert avi to 3gp using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, avi, mpeg-4

I want to convert an avi file to 3gp with codec as mpeg4 simple profile level 0.But i am not able to do it with ffmpeg,it gives this error-Requested output format ‘-vcodec’ is not a suitable output format.how to fix this help!thanks in advance
note - the input avi is 720x480 generated from bmp images using ffmpeg with codec ffv1.the output 3gp should be of mpeg4 simple profile level 0

Answer (score 1):

Original from: http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/322328-libfaac-encoding-with-ffmpeg

This worked for me:

```
tools/ffmpeg/./ffmpeg -i debug/assets/videos/sample_iPod.mp4 -acodec libvo_aacenc -vcodec libx264 debug/assets/videos/sample_iPod.3gp
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.. Hope this will help you

```
ffmpeg -i input.AVI -acodec libfaac -ab 128k -ar 44100 -s 704x400 -r 20 -vcodec libx264 -b 256000 -cmp +chroma -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -me_method umh -subq 5 -trellis 1 -refs 2 -bf 1 -coder 1 -me_range 16 -g 300 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -bt 256000 -maxrate 4M -bufsize 4M -rc_eq 'blurCplx^(1-qComp)' -qcomp 0.6 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -level 21 output.3gp
```

this will convert your avi to 3gp. Try different formats as input and output file as per your need

NOTE :- Change parameters as per your need like 'level'

Answer (score 0):

The guy wants it in mpeg4 codec not x264.

Here's how:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.avi -acodec libvo_aacenc -ab 64k -vcodec mpeg4 -s 320x240 -b:v 400k -r 23.976 output.3gp
```

In some phones 320x240 may seem stretchy, in that case use 320x180 instead

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
ffmpeg -y -i test.mpeg -r 20 -s 352x288 -b 400k -acodec aac -strict experimental -ac 1 -ar 8000 -ab 24k test.3gp
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code is working fine:

```
ffmpeg -y -i test.mpeg -r 20 -s 352x288 -b 400k -acodec aac -strict experimental -ac 1 -ar 8000 -ab 24k test.3gp
```